# Scala - Spark Word Count, why sliding not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to count the frequency of each bigram.

So I wrote

```
val intputFile = "bible+shakes.nopunc"
val sentences = sc.textFile(intputFile)

val bigrams = sentences.map(sentence => sentence.trim.split(' ')).flatMap( wordList =>
  for (i <- List.range(0, (wordList.length - 2))) yield ((wordList(i), wordList(i + 1)), 1)
)

val bigrams2 = sentences.map(sentence => sentence.trim.split(' ')).flatMap( wordList =>
  wordList.sliding(2).map{case Array(x, y) => ((x,y), 1)}
)
```

And they seems to have the same type.

```
scala> bigrams
res11: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, String), Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[7] at flatMap at <console>:28

scala> bigrams2
res12: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, String), Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[11] at flatMap at <console>:28
```

scala> bigrams.collect
res15: Array[((String, String), Int)] = Array(((holy,bible),1), ((bible,authorized),1), ((authorized,king),1), ((king,james),1), ((james,version),1), ((version,textfile),1), ((in,the),1), ((the,beginning),1), ((beginning,god),1), ((god,created),1), ((created,the),1), ((the,heaven),1), ((heaven,and),1), ((and,the),1), ((and,the),1), ((the,earth),1), ((earth,was),1), ((was,without),1), ((without,form),1), ((form,and),1), ((and,void),1), ((void,and),1), ((and,darkness),1), ((darkness,was),1), ((was,upon),1), ((upon,the),1), ((the,face),1), ((face,of),1), ((of,the),1), ((the,deep),1), ((deep,and),1), ((and,the),1), ((the,spirit),1), ((spirit,of),1), ((of,god),1), ((god,moved),1), ((moved,upon),1), ((upon,the),1), ((the,face),1), ((face,of),1), ((of,the),1), ((and,god),1), ((god,said),1), ((...

However, when I do so

```
scala> bigrams.collect
res13: Array[((String, String), Int)] = Array(((holy,bible),1), ((bible,authorized),1), ((authorized,king),1), ((king,james),1), ((james,version),1), ((version,textfile),1), ((in,the),1), ((the,beginning),1), ((beginning,god),1), ((god,created),1), ((created,the),1), ((the,heaven),1), ((heaven,and),1), ((and,the),1), ((and,the),1), ((the,earth),1), ((earth,was),1), ((was,without),1), ((without,form),1), ((form,and),1), ((and,void),1), ((void,and),1), ((and,darkness),1), ((darkness,was),1), ((was,upon),1), ((upon,the),1), ((the,face),1), ((face,of),1), ((of,the),1), ((the,deep),1), ((deep,and),1), ((and,the),1), ((the,spirit),1), ((spirit,of),1), ((of,god),1), ((god,moved),1), ((moved,upon),1), ((upon,the),1), ((the,face),1), ((face,of),1), ((of,the),1), ((and,god),1), ((god,said),1), ((...

scala> bigrams2.collect
16/10/05 10:17:52 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 20)
scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@3224ea91 (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)
    at $line27.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:29)

bigrams2.take(5)
res25: Array[((String, String), Int)] = Array(((holy,bible),1), ((bible,authorized),1), ((authorized,king),1), ((king,james),1), ((james,version),1))
```

The second way to evaluate it caused an error.

Why? How to fix it? I prefer the second, the precise way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your `wordList.sliding(2).map{case Array(x, y) => ((x,y), 1)` is that `{case Array(x, y) => ((x,y), 1)` is a `partial-function` whcih only knows how to deal with an input which matches the pattern `Array(x, y)`.

And thus you map will not be able to deal with the windows having just one element. You should change it to something like following,

```
wordList.sliding(2).flatMap {
  case Array(x, y) => Some((x, y), 1)
  case _ => None
}
```

Here, `flatMap` will flatten the `Option`s thus ensuring that the result contains only valid bi-grams.

Comment: You should mentioned that an `Option` can be considered a sequence that is either empty or has 1 item

Comment: @ShihaoXu Actually `Option` is not similar to a sequence that is either empty or has 1 item. It is just that for Scala beginners (or functional programming beginner)  explaining the actual definition of `Option` is not feasible and so people tell them to think of an `Option` that way. You can think of `Option` that way for now, but keep in mind that this is not actually true. And  you will naturally come to understand `Option` better once you have mastered a functional programming concept called `Monad`.

Answer (score 0):

Your bigrams2 expression has issue:

```
wordList.sliding(2).map{case Array(x, y) => ((x,y), 1)}
```

map cases does not handle the case when wordList has only one item, that is why your getting MatchError. It appears for sentences which single words.

To fix add case construction for array of one item:

```
wordList.sliding(2).map {
  case Array(x, y) => ((x,y), 1)
  case Array(x) => ???
}
```